# CrystalReports Stopped Working in Browser

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a crystal report in asp.net webform but the project is actually Asp.netMVC4. It used to work just fine in all browser but now it shows a blank page in the browser. If i do a preview it works just fine but on the browser shows blank. No error message shown.

Answer (score 0):

Please selecte any zooming option after preview......
Then check .........

Comment: Tnx for reply but i already found what the problem was. MVC really has bad handling of crystal reports. Apparently if you configure the routes to {resource}.axd the report shows but with no images. but if you comment this line to enable images it may mess up the routes in mvc.